# How to align my text to the bottom in my divs in a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I'm not able to align my text to the bottom of the divs in my flex content. I'm new to CSS and any help will be appreciated.

Thank you for your time and kindness.

```css
body,
html {
  background-color: #666666;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  color: #ffffff;
}

.flexTest {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
  border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.flexTest div {
  background-color: #EB710F;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="flexTest">
  <div>
    Tatactic - Nicolas 1
  </div>
  <div>
    Tatactic - Nicolas 2
  </div>
  <div>
    Tatactic - Nicolas 3
  </div>
  <div>
    Tatactic - Nicolas 4
  </div>
  <div>
    Tatactic - Nicolas 5
  </div>
  <div>
    Tatactic - Nicolas 6
  </div>
  <div>
    Tatactic - Nicolas 7
  </div>
  <div>
    Tatactic - Nicolas 8
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is thiis... add thies two properties

```
.flexTest div { 
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It works great too!!!
Thanks to both of You! +1

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work nicely

```
.flexTest div {
    background-color: #EB710F;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the flex children flex containers themselves. Note that I've modified the CSS selector to only target children of `.flexTest`.

```css
body,
html {
  background-color: #666666;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  color: #ffffff;
}

.flexTest {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
  border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.flexTest > div {
  background-color: #EB710F;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="flexTest">
  <div>
    Tatactic - Nicolas 1
  </div>
  <div>
    Tatactic - Nicolas 2
  </div>
  <div>
    Tatactic - Nicolas 3
  </div>
  <div>
    Tatactic - Nicolas 4
  </div>
  <div>
    Tatactic - Nicolas 5
  </div>
  <div>
    Tatactic - Nicolas 6
  </div>
  <div>
    Tatactic - Nicolas 7
  </div>
  <div>
    Tatactic - Nicolas 8
  </div>
</div>
```